# rails how to mapping a virtual view to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class CashOrderStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to:cash_order
end
```

usually the db need a table cash_order_statuses to mapping this model,but now i want to

mapping this model to a specific sql view like

```
select * from order_statues where cash_order_id is not null <=> CashOrderStatus
```

does rails provide some way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to fulfill your requirement:

1. In your CashOrderStatus model, you can set table name to override default ORM mapping:

```
class CashOrderStatus > ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "order_statuses"

  belongs_to:cash_order
end
```

1. You can implement STI(Single Table Inheritance) functionality where in your database table "order_statuses" one more column will be there: **type** which will hold the derived model class name(In this case, **CashOrderStatus**).

So your model will look like this:

```
class CashOrderStatus > OrderStatus
  set_table_name "order_statuses"

  belongs_to:cash_order
end
```

And OrderStaus model will be derived from AR::Base class. Try it.

**NOTE:** Sorry for the class inheritance notation. It should be **<** instead of **>**. There is formatting issue in my stackoverflow account, so I put like this :-)